# Pre 2000 US sci-fi movie featuring a wormhole

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

- **Language:** American/ English
- **Colour:** Yes
- **Live action:** Yes
- **Genre:** Action/ Sci-Fi
- **Location:** Space
- **Year:** Before 2000 / maybe 90's

I can barely remember anything about this movie but there is one scene I recall. There is some sort of black sphere about a meter or so wide in this room. The sphere pulls things toward it much like a black hole would.

They lower someone into it on a rope, and the rope keeps going and going. It's like some sort of wormhole, then communication with this person stops so they reel him back in and he's possibly dead as he's completely motionless.

I can confirm it's not "The Black Hole" by Disney. It's definitely an older US movie, probably from before 2000, possibly 90's.

Comment: The first thing that popped into my head was Event Horizon 1997. Do you remember if they were wearing space suits or regular clothes? By frozen do you mean visible signs of ice or they weren't moving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the similarities, I have decided to submit this as an answer. I think you may be looking for the 1997 film **[Event Horizon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119081/)**. It features a ship that has been lost for years and a team of people go to investigate.

The ship has a special gravity drive which generates an artificial black hole.

In one scene Justin goes into the "black hole" via a lifeline/rope. All hell breaks loose and when he returns his body floats in the zero gravity. While not dead he's definitely in a catatonic state.